# The datetime type in database is coming out as an array in json format, how can i get it to come out as a string?

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project in java, and when getting the information out of MySQL database in JSON format the DateTime types are being put in an array

```
 {"start":[2019,3,25,11,0],"end":[2019,3,25,14,0]}
```

I need them to be as a string. I'm not too familiar with spring so I don't know if there is an annotation I can use to stop this?

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/events")
@ResponseBody
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
List <Events> events (@RequestBody @RequestParam("to") 
@DateTimeFormat(iso= ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime start, 
@RequestParam("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime 
 end){

    System.out.println("Start DateTime: "+ start);
    System.out.println("End DateTime: "+ end);
    List<Events> eventsToreturn = eventService.findBetween(start, end);
    return eventService.findBetween(start, end);
}
```

I want this to return json format without the start and end being in an array.

Comment: Without your code we can't really know what you are doing.

Comment: Ive updated my code now, thanks

Comment: THis is the default `toString` representation of the `LocalDateTime` depending on which library you use register the correct Jackson module (JDK8 or JodaTime). Assuming you are using Jackson for the marshalling.

Comment: @JaneRyan You are returning a `List<Events>` but you haven't told us what is inside the `Events` class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have `jackson-datatype-jdk8` in your dependencies.

If you want the ISO 8601 format it is best if you use the `OffsetDateTime` class.

You should also configure jackson to disable `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` so that it is written in the right format.